# .NET Regex: replacing links and img src

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex

All,

I need to write a regular expression to perform the following operations
replace

**(A)**

```
src ="/folder/image.jpg"
```

or

```
src="http://www.mydomain.com/folder/image.jpg"
```

with

```
src="/cache/getCacheItem.aspx?source_url=http://www.mydomain.com/folder/image.jpg"
```

**(B)**

```
href="/folder/file.zip"
```

or

```
href="http://www.mydomain.com/folder/file.zip"
```

with

```
href="/cache/getCaccheItem.aspx?source_url=http://www.mydomain.com/folder/file.zip
```

I know I can use

```
(src|href).*?=['|\"](?<url>.*?)['|\"]
```

with a replace value of

```
$1="/legacy_integration/cache/getCacheItem.aspx?source_url=$2"
```

to catch the src=... and href=... attributes. However, I need to filter based on file extension - only match valid image extensions like jpg, png, gif, and only match href extensions like zip and pdf.

Any suggestions? The problem can be summarized as: modify the above expression to match only certain file extensions, and allow the domain **http://www.mydomain.com/** to be inserted only if the original url was a relative, thus ensuring that the output text contains the domain exactly once.

Do I need to perform this using two different regular expressions, one for source text including the domain and one without? Or can I somehow use a conditional match statement that, in combination with a replacement expression, will insert the domain or not based on whether the matched text contains the domain?

I know I can perform this using a custom match evaluator, but it seems that it may be faster/more efficient to do it within the regex itself.

Suggestions/comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following expression work?

```
Regex.Replace(url, 
@"(src|href)\s*=\s*(?:'|")((?:http://www\.mydomain\.com)?.*?(jpg|bmp|png))(?:'|")",
"$1 - /cache/getCacheItem.aspx?source_url=$2");
```

The idea is that you match the text http://www.mydomain.com conditionally.  It will be included as part of the $2 match text.  If it was there originally, it will make its way into the replaced string.

Answer (score 2):

This comes up *all the time*. Regex is not an appropriate tool to parse a non-regular grammar such as HTML. Use a real parser (like the [HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)) to do this.

Comment: I don't need to parse ALL HTML, just the specified tags. I also have control over the input data and can guarantee that the input text matches the given format. Seems like overkill to involve yet another 3rd party tool here.

Comment: It's not overkill, it's reliability, and it doesn't matter if you parse all if you parse any. Try it, it'll help solve many problems, not just this one.

Comment: While I appreciate the utterly stable approach, this particular solution as a) working, b) a temporary solution that allows me to present a LOT of legacy ASP content in a new ASP.NET framework, and c) working. As I said, I have control over the input data and can guarantee that my regex works. If I have need of a more general solution in the future, I'll happily explore the agility pack. Thanks. =)

Comment: Okay, I take it back. The HtmlAgilityPack is sweet.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will match any path, if you want constrain a path you can add it after the ?/.

```
(?<pre>(?:src|href)\W*=\W*(?:"|'))(?<url>(?:http://www\.mydomain\.com)?/(?<file>[^"']+))(?<post>"|')
```

Here's some sample code:

```
string pattern = "(?<pre>(?:src|href)\\W*=\\W*(?:\"|'))(?<url>(?:http://www\\.mydomain\\.com)?/(?<file>[^\"']+))(?<post>\"|')";

string test = "src =\"/folder/image.jpg\"\r\n"
            + "src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/folder/image.jpg\"\r\n"
            + "href=\"/folder/file.zip\"\r\n"
            + "href=\"http://www.mydomain.com/folder/file.zip\"";

string replacement = "${pre}/cache/getCacheItem.aspx?source_url=http://www.mydomain.com/${file}${post}";

test = Regex.Replace(test, pattern, replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var reg = new Regex("(/folder/[^\"]+)");
Match m = reg.Match("src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/folder/image.jpg\"");
var result = string.Format("src=\"/cache/getCacheItem.aspx? source_url=http://www.mydomain.com{0}\"", m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: @Espen P: It looks like this results in URLs that always contain http://www.mydomain.com.  From what I gather from the OP, David wants this domain included only if it was present in the original URL.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear - I want the domain included whether or not it was part of the original URL.